# Disable colored console output

Tags: logging, nestjs

Is it possible to disable the colored console output of the NestJS default logger? 
I can't find an option to turn it off :-(

*(Some more text, because this question is too simple for StackOverflow.)*

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The logger service uses module `cli-color`, setting environment variable `NO_COLOR` disables the output of color codes.

Answer (score 20):

While @Andreas's 2nd part of the answer is correct about setting the environment variable `NO_COLOR`, the first part is wrong. NestJS (at least as of v8) does not use the `cli-color` module (maybe earlier they were using it).

Seems they have implemented their own `clc` thing but they do respect the `NO_COLOR` flag.

Source code- https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/v8.0.8/packages/common/utils/cli-colors.util.ts#L3

And their [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#basic-customization) also says the same thing-

> **HINT**
> To disable color in the default logger's messages, set the `NO_COLOR` environment variable.

So below is the output in my local when running without the variable-

[image]

And this is when I do `export NO_COLOR=true`-

[image]

This works well in AWS CloudWatch logs as well.

Answer (score 3):

you can implementing your own custom logger. Simply implement each of the methods of the LoggerService interface as shown below.
import { LoggerService } from '@nestjs/common';

```
export class MyLogger implements LoggerService {
  log(message: string) {
    /* your implementation */
  }
  error(message: string, trace: string) {
    /* your implementation */
  }
  warn(message: string) {
    /* your implementation */
  }
  debug(message: string) {
    /* your implementation */
  }
  verbose(message: string) {
    /* your implementation */
  }
}

const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, {
  logger: new MyLogger(),
});
await app.listen(3000);
```

Rather than writing a logger from scratch, you may be able to meet your needs by extending the built-in Logger class and overriding selected behavior of the default implementation.

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

export class MyLogger extends Logger {
  error(message: string, trace: string) {
    // add your tailored logic here
    super.error(message, trace);
  }
}
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger

Answer (score -7):

In `NestFactory.create()` add options with `logger: false`

e.g. `await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule, { logger: false })`

Comment: This option turns off logging, but I want to disable the colored output -> no color codes in logfile.

Comment: Not sure that it's possible. Nestjs colorized log messages in `logger.service`, you can try to install `cli-color` _(Nestjs uses it)_ package and configure it locally in project

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This just disables logs.